# Proof of an identity with generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have some trouble with an exercise in discrete mathematics:

Show for $0\leq i\leq r-1$:

$$ 
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\binom{n-1}{r-i-1}t^n=\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{r-i}=\frac{t^{r-i}(1-t)^{i-1}}{(1-t)^{r-1}}.
$$

I really have some trouble to start on this on and every help is highly appreciated!

Kind regards.

Comment: There's two equalities there, which are you stuck on?

Comment: @B. Mehta: I'm willing to bet it's relating the sum to the closed form. The last two identities can be obtained from each other through elementary arithmetic/algebraic identities of powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{r-i}}&=t^{r-i}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-t)^{r-i}}\\
> &=t^{r-i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-(r-i)}{n}(-t)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=t^{r-i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+r-i-1}{n}t^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+r-i-1}{r-i-1}t^{n+r-i}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=r-i}^\infty\binom{n-1}{r-i-1}t^{n}\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{n-1}{r-i-1}t^{n}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we collect the terms in $t$ and use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (4) we shift the index to start from $n=r-i$.
- In (5) we observe $\binom{n-1}{r-i-1}=0$ for $1\leq n\leq r-i-1$ and start with $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{k+n-1}{k-1}x^n\tag{1}
$$
by differentiating the geometric series (where $k\geq 1$). In particular
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{r-i}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r-i+n-1}{r-i-1}x^n\tag{2}
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{x^{r-i}}{(1-x)^{r-i}}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r-i+[n-(r-i)]-1}{r-i-1}x^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n-1}{r-i-1}x^n\tag{3}
$$
since multiplying by $x^m$ ($m\geq 1$) shifts the coefficient from $a_n$ to $a_{n-m}$.